# Incremental history searching

Tags: command-line, search, history

I found this very useful tip in [UsingTheTerminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal) to use the arrow keys to search through the command history:

```
"\e[A": history-search-backward
"\e[B": history-search-forward
"\e[C": forward-char
"\e[D": backward-char
```

How can I change it in order to use `Ctrl+P` and `Ctrl+N` instead of the arrow keys?

Comment: You could also use $ history [numberOfCommandsToReturn]      if you just don't want to use the arrow keys.

Comment: Use `bind` command with selected option. For example for `Crtl+N` use `bind '"\C-n": history-search-backward'`

Comment: That worked. Do I have to copy it into my bashrc to make it permanent?

Comment: Yes, it needs to be placed in `.bashrc` or it will affect only current session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Repeating what I said in comment section to not leave question hanging without answer, in order to bind one of [Bash readline commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bindable-Readline-Commands.html#Bindable-Readline-Commands) you can use `bind` command. For example, <kbd>Crtl+N</kbd> shortcut can be used with:

```
$ bind '"\C-n": history-search-backward'
```

This will be limited to current session and needs to be placed inside `.bashrc` to have it established in every one.

Expanding my answer, you can also modify `~/.inputrc` file, as mentioned in link provided in question. There are two ways to do this. First syntax for same shortcut as above is:

```
"\C-n": history-search-backward
```

And the second one is:

```
Control-n: history-search-backward
```

This second type of syntax can be used with `bind` as well:

```
$ bind 'Control-n: history-search-backward'
```